# Whenever launched, terminal tries to execute export command and fails

Tags: linux-mint, terminal

I'm new to Linux. I use Linux Mint (Cinnamon), and every time I open the Terminal, I am greeted with this message:

```
Command '‘export' not found, did you mean:
  command 'mexport' from deb mblaze
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you `echo $version` do you get tcsh back?

Comment: it returns with nothing

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have edited your .bashrc file.

I can replicate this error exactly if I put

`'‘export'`

as the last line in my .bashrc

To check it just execute

`grep export ~/.bashrc`

If  `grep`  gives an output like the above then edit it out of your ~/.bashrc file.

Edit: From your last post edit you can see that you have 2 lines starting 'export delete them both from ~/.bashrc.